# Website,Email varification Regex

Tags: java, regex

This regex for email

```
"(\\s*[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+((co|gov).(in|uk)|com|gov|org|edu|in)\\s*)|" +
             "(\\s*(http\\://|www\\.|http\\://www\\.)?([\\w\\-]+\\.)+((co|gov)\\.(in|uk)|com|gov|org|edu|in)(( / )\\S*)*(\\s|$))"
```

can any one tell me the simplest regex? how can I write it in short form it is very complecated.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a regex for this. Java has what it takes to check the validity of an email address in javax.mail:

```
    try {
        new InternetAddress(theInput, true);
    } catch (AddressException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
```

Find the jar [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mailapi).

Comment: InternetAddress is predefined class or we need to create it?

Comment: See edit, I have posted a link to a place where you can get the jar

Comment: Aftercpattern matching i want to perform below operation on address.
What should i do for that? what that class return?
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
            while (m.find()) {
                String base = m.group();
                 String strtrget = base.trim();
                strtrget=strtrget.replaceAll("\\.","-@@@-");
                strtrget=strtrget.replaceAll(" ", "-");
                HashmapHypen.put(base, strtrget.replace("[-]+", "-"));
                input = input.replaceAll(base, " "+strtrget+" ");

Comment: before Matcher :
 try {
             input=input.replaceAll("http\\: / / ","http\\://");
             String expression = "(\\s*[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+((co|gov).(in|uk)|com|gov|org|edu|in)\\s*)|" +
             "(\\s*(http\\://|www\\.|http\\://www\\.)?([\\w\\-]+\\.)+((co|gov)\\.(in|uk)|com|gov|org|edu|in)(( / )\\S*)*(\\s|$))"; 
                        
    //  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression);

Comment: `InternetAddress` checks that the email is valid, that's all. What operations do you need to do after that? First of all you should get `InternetAddress` to work; only then consider operations. One step at a atime.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler is what fge has mentioned in his answer but if due to any reason you want to use regex, here is the one for email address validation:

> ^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*
>         @[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$;

Comment: `(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$` <-- it _is_ possible to have top level domains with one letter only, although no registered TLD does.

Comment: @fge good point, lets leave that for the questioner to figure out ;-)

Comment: @JunedAhsan: 10 years down the track: "Why has our email verification stopped?" ;)